# online converted eot file doesn 't work

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have converted 'Helvetica Neue Bold' ttf to eot online.. but it donesn't work in ie8 and below..

I have used this font face

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueBold';
    src: url('font/helveticaneue/helveticaneuebold.eot');
    src: url('font/helveticaneue/helveticaneuebold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/helveticaneue/helveticaneuebold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/helveticaneue/helveticaneuebold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/helveticaneue/helveticaneuebold.svg#HelveticaNeueBold') format('svg');

}
```

but it doesn't work in ie8 and below - in otherbrowser it works fine

can any body help me please - see "Prior to Leaving Checklist" header in followint link
url - http://d9692994.u118.c6.ixwebhosting.com/suitcase/check_list.html

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

IE pre-9 had it's own weird way of doing this.

Try this CSS hack:

```
@font-face {  
    font-family: "HelveticaNeueBold";  
    src: url("font/helveticaneue/helveticaneuebold.eot"); /* IE */  
    src: local("HelveticaNeueBold"), url("font/helveticaneue/helveticaneuebold.ttf") format("truetype"); /* non-IE */  
}
```

The `local` declaration IS required, because it will confuse IE (pre-10, it didn't support `local` in `@font-face` selectors) and force it to fall back on the previous `src` declaration.

This should work in IE4+.

Comment: I have tried this but still not working... can be there any problem with eot format file?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri Another possible issue could be the capitalization, try changing `font-family` to `helvericaneuebold`. EOT file must be the same name as `font-family`, don't know if it's case sensitive but worth trying.

Comment: I have changed font-family to lower case - still doesn't work